# Why do we use Comparator over Comparable apart from the reason that it helps in customised sorting order?

Tags: java, collections, comparator, comparable

Comparator is used when we want to achieve customised sorting order but that is also possible with Comparable. So why do we use Comparator?

Comment: "that is also possible with Comparable" - not really. If you've got (say) a `Person` class with date of birth and name, and sometimes you want to sort a list of people by name, and sometimes by age, how would you do that with `Comparable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why do we use `Comparator`?

Some of the reasons include:

- Because `Comparable` only allows you to define one sort order.   Some applications require more than one sort order; e.g. name order versus age order, or name order versus *reverse* name order.
- Because you may not be able to customize the type.  For example, you can't customise the sort order of `String` because `String` is a `final` class.
- Because it may be inappropriate to customize the sort order for the class.  For example, it may not make sense for the class to have any *natural* ordering at all.

---

Anyway, `Comparator` provides an alternative to `Comparable`.  You don't have to use it if you don't want to.